# Tightened type checking rules for pattern bindings in Scala 3.2+

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, scala-3

From Scala 3.2 and on, this pattern binding results in a compiler warning:

```scala
val tuples = List((1, 2), (3, 4))
val head :: tail = tuples
```

The warning reads:

> pattern's type `::[(Int, Int)]` is more specialized than the right hand side expression's type `List[(Int, Int)]`

> If the narrowing is intentional, this can be communicated by adding `: @unchecked` after the expression,
> which may result in a MatchError at runtime.

I've read [the respective article on dotty.epfl.ch](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/pattern-bindings.html), yet I fail to understand how this is "unchecked". Is it not so that we can safely determine, at compile-time, that `head` is of type `(Int, Int)` and `tail` is of type `List[(Int, Int)]`? Where did I take the wrong turn here?

Comment: I think the issue here is that if `tuples` is the empty list then this will throw an exception.